# Search and replace in vi using specific loop

Tags: loops, search, replace, vi

Hello, I have a specific need.
In a .txt file I have several lines, the content is like this:

```
   ABC, Srl
   Progettazione componenti plastici tecnici
   REGGIO EMILIA, Italia
   MECCANICA PIPPO, Snc
   Lavorazione dei metalli
   NOVELLARA, Italia
   SALDATURE, Srl
   Produzione di componenti meccanici
   RUBIERA, Italia
   OLEODINAMICA PAPERINO, Srl
   Produzione di centraline oleodinamiche
   GUASTALLA, Italia
```

Since 3 lines belong to the same element, I need to:
1) substitute \n with ; and get only 3 lines on the same row separated by ;
2) then have a \n
3) and finally repeat the commands in a loop

In this way I should get the following:

```
   ABC, Srl;Progettazione componenti plastici tecnici;REGGIO EMILIA, Italia  
   MECCANICA PIPPO, Snc; Lavorazione dei metalli;NOVELLARA, Italia
   SALDATURE, Srl; Produzione di componenti meccanici; RUBIERA, Italia
   OLEODINAMICA PAPERINO, Srl; Produzione di centraline oleodinamiche; GUASTALLA, Italia
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should [edit] the question to show what you've already tried or researched. See [ask].

Comment: provide proper code format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you didn't say what OS or version of `vi` but in `vim` on Linux you could create a macro containing the commands required then run that macro.  You can do the same thing in other version of vi, you'll just have to look up the right commands.  For example in vim, in the editor with your file containing 12 lines of 4 real records open, position to the first line then run these commands  (my comments follow, don't type them):

```
qz       # q to start recording a macro into register z
Jr;Jr;j  # J to join 2 lines. r; to replace the space with a semi-colon. 
         #   Repeat, then j to move down a line.
q        # Stop recording the macro.
```

Move to the first line of the next set and type

```
@z
```

to run the macro stored in register 'z'.  Proceed the command by a number to run it that many times.  So now there are 2 sets left.  Position to the first of those and type:

```
2@z
```

Once you have the macro created, run it on all lines with this command:

```
:%norm! @z
```

Comment: This...is...simply...AMAZING! :)
Thanks, very useful and fast, done on my Mac OS X.